# Change label text for multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, jquery-selectors

I have a dynamic page that can have a lot of `input[type="file"]` fields. I need to change the label of every input once a file is selected.

So, for each input, if:

- Empty: text = "upload";
- File selected: text = name of file.

Here is a sample of HTML:

```
<label for="upload-qm1">
    <span class="button">upload</span>
    <input id="upload-qm1" type="file" accept=".pdf, .doc">
</label>
```

I know how to do this for a single `input`, using this code:

```
$('label[for="upload-qm1"] span').text($(this).val());
```

However, I don't know how many `input` fields I will have on my page. I tried something like this:

```
$(this).parent('label').find('span').text($(this).val());
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work. Any help on how I can get a method for changing all `input` fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use DOM traversal to find the `span` related to the `input` which was changed. Try this:

```
$('input:file').change(function() {
    $(this).prev('span').text($(this).val());
})
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/yafpngs0/)

Answer (score 0):

The most of the code you tried ist corret.
The problem is that you have set a parameter for the `parent()` function.

Try something like this:
`$(this).parent('label').find('span').text($(this).val());`

Also make sure that `$(this)` is the input field not the label itself,
if you click on the label `$(this)` is the label.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $('input[type="file"]').on('change', function() {
        id = $(this).attr('id');
           console.log("change event")
        var file = $('#'+id).val().split('\\').pop(); 
        if(file!='')  { 
             $('label[for="'+id+'"] span').text(file)
        } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="upload-qm1">
  <span class="button">upload</span>
  <input id="upload-qm1" type="file" accept=".pdf, .doc">
</label>
```